# Создание моделей по существующей базе данных в Rails-приложении

Tags: model, postgresql, ruby-on-rails

Здравствуйте, такой вопрос: нужно написать приложение на рельсах, которое будет работать с существующей базой данных.

Создавать модели вручную не вариант. Как можно сгенерировать модели, с учетом схем postgres?

Пробовал использовать гем legacy_data, но не запустился, видимо из за несовместимости с рельсами > 3.0

Comment: Написать генератор, который будет по схеме генерить модели?

Comment: Чтоб работать с БД достаточно любого менеджера к соответствующей базе.

А вообще пишут приложение, которое хранит в БД свои данные, и может быть какую-то часть логики, которую быстрее и надежнее выполнять на стороне БД.

Comment: @Чад это конечно вариант, но разве ничего готового нет?

Comment: В данном случае, мне кажется Вы быстрее напишете свой генератор, чем будете искать готовое решение, а потом допиливать его под себя. Задача то с одной стороны не сложная, а с другой стороны - не тривиальная т.к. в базе может быть не полная информация для того чтобы однозначно построить модели.

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете адаптировать существующую базу данных для Rails-приложения. Однако, вам скорее всего потребуется явно переопределить методы с названиями базы данных и таблиц, так как они будут отсутствовать в миграциях и следовательно в схеме.

```
def self.database
  'database_name'
end

def self.table_name
  'table_name'
end
```

Из подводных камней, которые вам могут встретиться при использовании легаси базы данных в Rails-приложении, это специальные поля вроде `type`, которое в Rails-приложении является признаком STI-таблицы. Подавить интерпретацию модели как STI при наличии поля `type`, можно задав в модели следующую строку

```
self.inheritance_column = :_type_disabled
```

Отдельно следует упомянуть название первичного ключа `id`, в сторонних базах данных, оно может называться по-другому, или наоборот поле `id` не должно интерпретироваться в качестве первичного ключа, в этом случае можно прибегнуть к алиасам

```
alias_attribute :external_id, :id
```

Аналогично можно действовать в отношении остальных полей, например, `created_at` - времени создания записи:

```
alias_attribute :published_at, :publication_date
```

Все перечисленные выше строки записываются в теле класса модели, которая будет обращаться к легаси-базе данных.